# Is there any event after completly loading of angular js Scope elements and Directives and Http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I want to call a javascript function after http request send data to controller and after data binding to controller . is there any such angular method ?

Answer (score 0):

$timeout would be your best bet for knowing that controllers and binding is done. However this requires you to be withing the Angular lifecycle. There is no events to know that HTTP requests are pending or complete, you would need to track the status of the ones you are interested in.

If you are trying to call a plain JavaScript function from outside the Angular lifecycle I would question what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to implement datatables from ajax request, and convert dropdown to select2 controls after data binded from http requests

Comment: The correct way to do that would be to create a wrapper for the JQuery creation code. Initializing the component in the link function of the directive, doing the data request in the link function and once it resolves calling the update function on the component.

Comment: Honestly attempting to wrap JQuery components or any other javascript component in Angular is more work than it is ever worth.

Comment: To make you life easier you should take a look at: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select
Which is Select2 as a native Angular widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using the flag.

1. on controller put ng-if="somevariableflag"

on success of http request set this variable to be true .Now ur dom rendering will take place .. To know ng-repeat is completed or not create a directive like

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="test in testing" repeat-completed>
    {{test}}
  </div>
</div> 

angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('repeat-completed', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
      //do whatever you want to do
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using "$watch" service.

$watch service continuously watch the model. Whenever there is change in value of model, it runs listener function

```
    Syntax: scope.$watch('watchExpression ( this can be your model )' , function() {
   // this is a listener function you can define here
   // actions to perform
})
```

Please follow the link attached below.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch